# How to count the number of persons with values present in n columns of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like below,

```
Subject Id     Site1    Site2    Site3    Site4
A               23       34        NaN     NaN
B               NaN      30        40      56
C               NaN      NaN       NaN     36
D               25       NaN       NaN     NaN
E               40       35        NaN     46
```

How do I count the number of subjects with value present in all the 4 sites?

Comment: what is your expected output in the above data?

Comment: `df.iloc[:,1:].notna().all(1).sum()`.

Comment: Suppose we have other columns as well, how do I use Site_ to make sure that I only get the number of patients with data present in Site_ columns and the code ignores the rest of the columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `df.filter` to get your `"Site"` columns, then use the method Quang Hoang specified in the comments.

```
df.filter(like="Site").notna().all(1).sum()
```

If you have other columns with the substring "Site" in them, you can use a quick regular expression to increase the selectivity:

```
df.filter(regex="^Site\d+$").notna().all(1).sum()
```